# How to find MongoDB document and compare to data posted to server

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to server-side programming, and I'm trying to understand how to send data server-side, find a document in a collection and compare it against that data, and then send a status back to the client depending on whether or not it exists.

Here's what's being sent server-side via the `/login` post request:

`{"email":"johndoe@gmail.com","password":"pass"}`

Here's the document I'm wanting to compare against in the `users` collection in my DB:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("580bcf9874ae28934705c0fc"),
    "email" : "johndoe@gmail.com",
    "password" : "pass"
}
```

And here's my server-side script *(areas I'm guessing are problematic have comments above them)*:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var fs = require("fs");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use(express.static("./public"));

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', function (err, db) {

    app.post("/login", function(req, res) {

        var emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        var userInDb;

        // ***** HERE 1 ******
        db.collection("users").findOne( {"email": req.body["email"], "password": req.body["password"]} ).toArray(function(err, results) {

            userInDb = results;         
            db.close();

        });

        // ***** HERE 2 ******
        var emailInDb = userInDb["email"];
        var passwordInDb = userInDb["password"];

        if (!req.body["email"] || !req.body["password"]) {
            res.sendStatus(403);
        } else if ( !emailRegex.test(req.body["email"])) {
            res.sendStatus(403);
        } else if ( (req.body["email"] != emailInDb) && (req.body["password"] != passwordInDb) ) {
            res.sendStatus(403);
        } else {
            res.sendStatus(200);
        }

    });
});
```

I've also experimented with the following in place of the "HERE 1" section:

```
var findUser = function (db, callback) {
  var users = db.collection("users");
  users.findOne({"email": req.body["email"], "password": req.body["password"]}).toArray(function(err, results) {
    userInDb = results;
    callback(results);
});
```

**=================== EDIT ========================**

Here's what it looks like after implementing the below:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', function (err, db) {

    app.post("/login", function(req, res) {

        var emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        var userInDb;

        if (!req.body["email"] || !req.body["password"]) {
            return res.sendStatus(403);
        } else if ( !emailRegex.test(req.body["email"])) {
            return res.sendStatus(403);
        } else {

            db.collection("users").findOne( {"email": req.body["email"], "password": req.body["password"]}, function(err, results) {

              if(err || !result) {
                return res.sendStatus(403);
              } else {
                userInDb = results;             
                db.close();
                return res.sendStatus(200);
              }

            });

         }

     });
});
```

But I'm getting this error in the terminal:

```
POST request for '/login' - {"email":"johndoe@gmail.com","password":"pass"}
TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined at app.js:30:6
```

Here's what's at line 30:

```
db.collection("users").findOne( {"email": req.body["email"], "password": req.body["password"]}, function(err, results) {
```

Does the collection need to be stored somewhere other than the `/db/data/` folder you set up when installing MongoDB, do I need to `mongoose.connect` directly to the `users` collection, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

findOne is an async function, you have to put the code above here 2 on the callback like this :

```
db.collection("users").findOne( {"email": req.body["email"], "password": req.body["password"]} ).toArray(function(err, results) {

        // ***** HERE 2 ******
       var emailInDb = userInDb["email"];
       var passwordInDb = userInDb["password"];

       .....
});
```

Then, you forget to check error and result,

```
db.collection("users").findOne( {"email": req.body["email"], "password": req.body["password"]} ).toArray(function(err, results) {

        if(err || !result)
            res.sendStatus(403);

           // ***** HERE 2 ******
          var emailInDb = userInDb["email"];
          var passwordInDb = userInDb["password"];

       .....
});
```

Then, you call findOne with the toArray function, why ? You only want 1 result, you don't need to transformed it. In addition you don't use the result as an array, so replace it with

```
db.collection("users").findOne( {"email": req.body["email"], "password": req.body["password"]}, function(err, results) {

        if(err || !result)
            return res.sendStatus(403);

           // ***** HERE 2 ******
          var emailInDb = userInDb["email"];
          var passwordInDb = userInDb["password"];

       .....
});
```

Finally, do control before mongo call to prevent useless db call and no need to check  (req.body["email"] != emailInDb) && (req.body["password"] != passwordInDb) as it has been already done in mongo query.

Final code :

```
var emailInDb = userInDb["email"];
var passwordInDb = userInDb["password"];

if (!req.body["email"] || !req.body["password"]) {
    return res.sendStatus(403);
} else if ( !emailRegex.test(req.body["email"])) {
    return res.sendStatus(403);
} else {

db.collection("users").findOne( {"email": req.body["email"], "password": req.body["password"], function(err, results) {
        if(err || !result)
            return res.sendStatus(403);
        else
        {
           userInDb = results;             
           db.close();
           return res.sendStatus(200);
        }
    });
   });
 }
```

Other optimisations :

you don't need to put your call in the mongo db connect callback.

hash your password in db

================ EDIT =============
Don't use db.collection

File app.js

```
var mongoose        = require("mongoose");
var User = require("./models/User");

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017');
app.post("/login", function(req, res) {
  var emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  var userInDb;

  if (!req.body["email"] || !req.body["password"]) {
      return res.sendStatus(403);
  } else if ( !emailRegex.test(req.body["email"])) {
      return res.sendStatus(403);
  } else {

      Users.findOne( {"email": req.body["email"], "password": req.body["password"]}, function(err, results) {

        if(err || !results) {
          return res.sendStatus(403);
        } else {
          return res.sendStatus(200);
        }
      });
   }
});

app.listen(....
```

File models/User.js

```
var mongoose  = require('mongoose');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // auth fields
  email:        {type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true },
  password:       {type: String, default: ""}
  ... other fields
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. I updated the post with additional information.

Comment: I'm not familiar with schemas yet, so apologies if this is a dumb question, but without searching for a document in that db collection how would I find the user?